# Custom browser with pyqt that can carry a session [PYQT4] [PY2.7]

Tags: python, pyqt, python-requests

I need to make a browser that can open with preset cookies given from a requests.Session(), then work carry the cookies like a session. I tried using pyqt webkit, but the session does not carry.I am trying to avoid Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Python27 has [cookielib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html).
You should be able to convert cookies forth and back to whatever `(cookielib.MozillaCookieJar/dict/...)` is needed by various libraries.

Comment: I want to use pyqt webkit, but it seems that after every new page it clears the cookies, even if I set the cookiejar